# How to create a button in connfluence page with rest api

Tags: json, api, confluence, confluence-rest-api, confluence-macros

I create a page with confluence rest api.
for example:

post http://127.0.0.1:8080/rest/api/content

```
{
    "type":"page",
    "status":"current",
    "title":"this is my first page",
    "space":{"key":"ymapi"},
    "body":{"storage":{"value":"<div><button>Click</button></div>","representation":"storage"}}
}
```

but the buttonn cannot be shown

Answer (score 0):

Use a link (and style it to look like a button) from one of the examples in here:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/confluence-storage-format-790796544.html#ConfluenceStorageFormat-Links